# Why is requiring login on every page my django app on heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I deployed a django web-app on Heroku. It has some views that require login and others that doesn't. If I set `DEBUG = False` on settings.py and push to Heroku, then all the URLS with the domain of my app require login. For Example:

1. If I try to access to `example.herokuapp.com` then it will redirect me to `example.herokuapp.com/accounts/login/?next=/` which is fine, beacause `example.herokuapp.com` require login to display
2. If I try to access to `example.herokuapp.com/accounts/signup/` then it will redirect me to `example.herokuapp.com/accounts/login/?next=/accounts/signup/` which shouldn't happen, because `example.herokuapp.com/accounts/signup/` doesn't require login
3. If I try to access to `example.herokuapp.com/blablablabla` then it will redirect me to `https://cafa.herokuapp.com/accounts/login/?next=/blablablabla` which isn't right, because `example.herokuapp.com/blablablabla` is not even an included url in my app.

I'm not sure how to fix this and I haven't find anything useful to guide myself to a solution.

If it's necessary that I show part of the code I'll be happy to do it if that helps to find a solution.

Here is the code:

settings.py:

```py
DEBUG = True
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'login.apps.LoginConfig',
# .... other apps
]
```

views.py from login app:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group


def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            group = Group.objects.get(name='Colaboradores')
            user.groups.add(group)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('redireccion_home')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/registro.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import views
from login.forms import UserLoginForm

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('login.urls')),
    path(
        'accounts/login/',
        views.LoginView.as_view(
            authentication_form=UserLoginForm
            ),
    ),
# other urls
]
```

Comment: please upload the relevant code

Comment: Is that enough?